# Точки в системе координат

Tags: функции

```
 y(x) = a * x + b;
```

Задание расшифровать выражение усно

Comment: Вы чересчур подробно описали свою проблему. Уберите из вопроса лишнее описание. Имхо, одного уравнения было бы достаточно чтобы разобраться в вопросе.

Comment: Что значит y(x)    ?

Comment: @ВиталийVit а что значит "усно"?

Answer (score 1):

Функция игрек от икс в виде линейной функции с двумя параметрами. А икс плюс бэ.

Если прочитать [вслух](https://api.naturalreaders.com/v2/tts/?t=funkcia%20igrek%20ot%20iks%20s%20dvumya%20peremennimi%20a%20i%20b.%20a%20gpomnojit%20na%20iks%20plus%20b&r=6&s=1&requesttoken=fac0170f86e700c9df42a3e8e6cbe3b9), то думаю, это то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Что значит y(x)   это умножить ?

Comment: т е что бы проверить находится точка в графике функции или нет что нужно сравнить варианты ответа например

Comment: y = a*x+b;       yx = a*x+b;      x = a*x +b;